# Are there Silverlight assemblies for Windows Azure SDK 1.2

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, azure, azure-storage

Just wondering if there are Silverlight (4) versions of the following assemblies

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these libraries are not compatible with silverlight. First, the ServiceRuntime and Diagnostics libraries are completely useless to silverlight. Those are only relevant to hosted roles. As far as the StorageClient, while there is no dll for that there are a number of different approaches. I would recommend using the newly release RIA services for table storage as part of your solution. You can find that here: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

Also see this discussion for more details. Basically, you will want to use WCF services to expose you blob storage, etc. to your silverlight client. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/b5e6775a-289f-438d-be79-8414f08c5c78

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I was looking at the diagnostics from a Silverlight Client to view logs etc.  I can easily exposes RIA or OData services instead